# tenses of a sentence, but with a qualifier date

Tags: grammar, tenses

Tried searching for this but not sure what to call it...

So I have three sentences and I'm wondering what their tenses are (I'm learning another language and I think it will be easier to understand English grammar better so as to use the "rules" to learn the other);

```
1.) On Sunday, all our friends *will go* to the summer home.
2.) On Sunday, all our friends *are going* to the summer home.
3.) On Sunday, all our friends *went* to the summer home.
4.) On Sunday, all our friends *had gone* to the summer home.
```

By looking at Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_tense I think that;

```
1.) simple future
2.) continuous present
3.) simple past
4.) perfect past
```

*But* I'm afraid that the "On Sunday" has an influence on the test-aspect of the sentence. Some context;

```
1.) Maybe this first sentence is said to a friend a couple days before Sunday.
2.) Is this still future (of which type?)? Or is it present? 

In the present tense (of what type I don't know), I can think this sentence being stated by two friends who are in the process of going to the summer home, and one says this to the other in order to emphasize that that is what they are doing. Kind of obvious and a little strange but still a valid context. 

3.) This could be the sentence stated a couple days afterwards.
4.) Same as 3.)
```

Summary: What effect does "On Sunday" have on the sentences and their tenses?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [*I think it will be easier to understand English grammar better so as to use the "rules" to learn the other*]  It might: it's certainly helpful to know some grammatical terminology.  Just don't expect that the English tenses will necessarily all have equivalents in the other language or vice versa, and don't expect that their uses will line up exactly with ours even where formally the tenses appear equivalent.

Comment: Sage advice... I've already discovered that though, but still sometimes it helps me :)